# Copying AdSense on page using jQuery - is it against AdSense rules?

Tags: ajax, load, adsense

I need loading Google Adsense Ads with AJAX. I found, that it's not allowed at this time, so I was thinking and invet this:

I normally include Google javascript code into HTML page in DIV with some ID like:

```
<div id="google_ad">
  <script>
  google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";                            
  google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
  google_ad_width = 300;
  google_ad_height = 250;
  </script>
  <script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
</div>
```

And then, when I'm loading new content via AJAX, I create new DIV with some CLASS and then copy content of  into every  like this:

```
$('#content').append($('<div>').load('http://www.foo.com/load.php'), function(){
  $('.google_ad').html($('#google_ad').html());
}));
```

Do you thing that it's ok or it's against Google AdSense rules?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What are you getting by copying the adsense code. I think this won't cause new impression.

Comment: I think that I don't need new impression, I simply copy the HTML code generatade via AdSense javascript embed in page with my ID and when user click on copied HTML link, Google recognize, that user click on the ad on my website and add some fee to my AdSense account.

Answer (score 0):

I am an Adsense publisher since 2006, your ajax trick looks cool. So you mean your full and unaltered Google adsense code is inside the load.php file ?

According to [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/adsense/i-have-an-active-account-working-with-adsense) (google forum) loading your Adsense code via ajax is same as loading your adsense code via IFRAME.

So to protect your adsense account, put your adsense code naturally.